# Does Windows 8 Has The Ability To Read/Write NFC Tags?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I've tried downloading and deployed the Proximity Sample Code [**link**](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Proximity-Sample-88129731). But i'm unable to do anything with regards to NFC.

Then i did a search on YouTube and found [**this**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiPNzJB3mq0). Is this even NFC? From what i know, NFC stands for Near Field Communication and typically, they can only receive/transmit data when the tag/device is of close proximity (1-2 cm away).

I'm using an SCL3711 hardware. I've tried using running the Sample Code provided by the hardware maker - [**IDENTIVE**](http://www.indentive.se/). It works alright if i'm creating a WPF project. Some classes don't exist on WindowsRT (In particular, System.Windows.Form.Message).

All i need is an application that can develop a Windows 8 (Windows Store) application that is able to read **and** write data to an NFC tag. Any help is appreciated.